# Problem when launching the bot due to quick.db

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a problem with my bot discord I updated everything better sqlite quick DB but when I launch the bot always the same error someone could help me?

```
PS C:\Users\berno\Desktop\Bot-Parfait-main> node index.js
C:\Users\berno\Desktop\Bot-Parfait-main\index.js:7
const table = new db.table('Prefix');
              ^

TypeError: db.table is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\berno\Desktop\Bot-Parfait-main\index.js:7:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49

Node.js v20.11.0
PS C:\Users\berno\Desktop\Bot-Parfait-main>
```

And there was my code :

```
const { Client, Intents, guild, Collection } = require('discord.js');
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const config = require('./config')
const { readdirSync } = require("fs")
const { QuickDB } = require("quick.db");
const db = new QuickDB();
const table = new db.table('Prefix');
const logembed = new db.table("embedlog")
ms = require("ms")
const color = config.app.color
const client = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_BANS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INTEGRATIONS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_WEBHOOKS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INVITES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING],
    restTimeOffset: 0,
    partials: ["USER", "CHANNEL", "GUILD_MEMBER", "MESSAGE", "REACTION"]
});

client.login(config.app.token);
client.commands = new Collection();

const { GiveawaysManager } = require('discord-giveaways');
client.giveawaysManager = new GiveawaysManager(client, {
    storage: "./database.json",
    updateCountdownEvery: 3000,
    default: {
        botsCanWin: false,
        embedColor: "#FF0000",
        reaction: ""
    }
});
```

Thanks Advance !

I installed the last update and updated the code. I did everything I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is quite clear, you can't construct a new instance from `db.table` now on QuickDB. You can go ahead and access `db.table('Prefix')` without the `new` keyword. This is because the table function on QuickDB doesn't need the `new` keyword again. You can read more on the [migration guide here](https://plexidev.gitbook.io/quickdb/overview/migration-guide#table)

Update your code to access `db.table` directly like below and everything should work properly.

```
const table = db.table('Prefix');
const logembed = db.table("embedlog")
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hello thanks you its works ! But i get new problem with http request i go to kill me x)

Comment: Great! Upvote my answer if the solution I gave helped solve your issue.

Comment: What new problem are you having with the http request?

Comment: I make a new subject on that with code and error if you want to view

Comment: @Yoda's Upvote my answer here if it helped you. Then, send a link to the new question you have created.

Comment: I make normaly can you view my new question

Comment: Drop a link to the new question here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77947842/problem-with-http-request-get-and-discord-bot