# Problem with http request "get" and discord bot

Tags: discord, discord.js

after having fixed with the help of the bugs forum I have the last bug ... that I did not find here and nowhere ... here is my error

```
HTTPError [FetchError]: request to https://discord.com/api/v9/gateway/bot failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at RequestHandler.execute (D:\Bot-Parfait-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:201:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (D:\Bot-Parfait-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async WebSocketManager.connect (D:\Bot-Parfait-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:134:9)
    at async Client.login (D:\Bot-Parfait-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:254:7) {
  code: 500,
  method: 'get',
  path: '/gateway/bot',
  requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
} Promise {
  <rejected> HTTPError [FetchError]: request to https://discord.com/api/v9/gateway/bot failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
      at RequestHandler.execute (D:\Bot-Parfait-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:201:15)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async RequestHandler.push (D:\Bot-Parfait-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
      at async WebSocketManager.connect (D:\Bot-Parfait-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:134:9)
      at async Client.login (D:\Bot-Parfait-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:254:7) {
    code: 500,
    method: 'get',
    path: '/gateway/bot',
    requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
  }
}
```

And here is my code :

```
    // Perform the request
    let res;
    try {
      res = await request.make();
    } catch (error) {
      // Retry the specified number of times for request abortions
      if (request.retries === this.manager.client.options.retryLimit) {
        throw new HTTPError(error.message, error.constructor.name, error.status, request);
      }

      request.retries++;
      return this.execute(request);
    }

    if (this.manager.client.listenerCount(API_RESPONSE)) {
      /**
       * Emitted after every API request has received a response.
       * This event does not necessarily correlate to completion of the request, e.g. when hitting a rate limit.
       * <info>This is an informational event that is emitted quite frequently,
       * it is highly recommended to check `request.path` to filter the data.</info>
       * @event BaseClient#apiResponse
       * @param {APIRequest} request The request that triggered this response
       * @param {Response} response The response received from the Discord API
       */
      this.manager.client.emit(
        API_RESPONSE,
        {
          method: request.method,
          path: request.path,
          route: request.route,
          options: request.options,
          retries: request.retries,
        },
        res.clone(),
      );
    }
```

Thanks advance !

I tried to look for the cause of the error on forums and stuff but I couldn't find it... I don't know much about it.

Comment: Have you checked your SSL/TLS certificates?

Comment: Normaly all is good for ssl tls